# MATLAB's eigs returning very odd results

Tags: matlab, eigenvector

I have a sparse, real, symmetric matrix which I'm trying decompose into its e.v. 
The odd thing is: if I calculate the top 20 eigen-vectors using eigs, I get different results than if I calculate the top 50 and then pick out the top 20.

```
opts.v0 = rand(size(K,1),1);
opts.p = 100;

n_ev = 20;
[V,D] = eigs(K, n_ev,'lm',opts);
Display(V,79,95,size(V,1)/(79*95),20)

n_ev = 50;
[V,D] = eigs(K, n_ev,'lm',opts);
Display(V,79,95,size(V,1)/(79*95),20)

n_ev = 70;   
[V,D] = eigs(K, n_ev,'lm',opts);
Display(V,79,95,size(V,1)/(79*95),20)
```

- Display is a function I wrote that reshapes those E.V's and displays the top 20 (5th argument).

Can this be explained by the fact that eigen-vectors are not unique?
Any other insights would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you use `eig` to compute all the eigenvectors and then pick the first 20? Also it would be nice if you could provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE), because the code you posted, naturally, cannot be run.

Comment: "I get different results ...." What are the results and how are they different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to John [in a mathworks post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/224516-why-matlab-function-eigs-has-different-results-for-the-same-input-data)

> This is because eigs uses a random start

Since `eigs` is a [ARPACK](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/arpack/arpack.html) library it could be time consuming to read through its documentation. However we can assume that 1) it does not try to solve the inverse matrix and 2) random number is involved so output has random error.

An experiment is done:

```
clear;clc;close all

K = randn(100);

N = 20;
DD = zeros(N,10);
for ii = 1:10
    [V,D] = eigs(K, N,'lm');
    DS = diag(D);
    [~,DI] = sort(abs(DS),'descend');
    DS = DS(DI);
    DD(:,ii) = DS;
end
DN1 = abs(DD);

N = 50;
DD = zeros(N,10);
for ii = 1:10
    [V,D] = eigs(K, N,'lm');
    DS = diag(D);
    [~,DI] = sort(abs(DS),'descend');
    DS = DS(DI);
    DD(:,ii) = DS;
end
DN2 = abs(DD);
DN2 = DN2(1:20,:);

N = 20;
DD = zeros(N,10);
for ii = 1:10
    [V,D] = eigs(K, N,'lm');
    DS = diag(D);
    [~,DI] = sort(abs(DS),'descend');
    DS = DS(DI);
    DD(:,ii) = DS;
end
DN3 = abs(DD);
```

which follows your procedure: first top 20, then top 50, and then top 20. In each step, same procedure is repeated 10 times.

I have saved the top 20 of each step and did a quick comparison:

```
Err = (sum((DN1-DN2).^2+(DN2-DN3).^2+(DN1-DN3).^2,1)).^.5;
>> Err

Err =

  Columns 1 through 6

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0870    0.0000    0.0000

  Columns 7 through 10

    0.0000    0.0000    0.0870    0.0870

>> min(Err),max(Err)

ans =

   3.1665e-13


ans =

    0.0870

>>
```

For most of the times the error is comparable to `eps(1)` but a few error is big. This suggests that in order to generate a reliable result, repeated calculation and averaging may be required.

---

However if your question is merely they are out of order (I think I got your point now), you could `sort` the vector with respect to the magnitudes after the evaluation. My experiment should be able to prove that after the `sort` the top 20 are always the same.

---

Edit: As @TroyHaskin has pointed out in comments you have defined `opts` (and I blatantly removed it) to define the random seeds. Let's add those lines and see what happens with the error:

```
Err =

  Columns 1 through 6

    0.0016    0.0016    0.0016    0.0016    0.0016    0.0016

  Columns 7 through 10

    0.0016    0.0016    0.0016    0.0016
```

Possible (guessed) explanation: as the number of interested e.v. increases the error grows since "some" tolerance is loosened to guarantee the speed performance.

Comment: It does.  But I'm still waiting to see what the OP defines as "different" since it is rather vague at this point.